# Selecting multiple columns from each row and removing duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Say I have a table with the following structure:

```
- Id
- Phone1
- Phone2
- Address
```

This table has multiple records.
What's the best way, using linq to SQL, of selecting all the phone numbers (from columns "Phone1" and "Phone2") in each row, and also removing repeated values.

I've tried something like but I can only get one column (Phone1) in each row:

```
var listOfResults = (from x in table
                     select x.Select(z => z.Phone1).Distinct() 
                     ).ToList();
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var listOfPhone1 = (from x in table select x.Select(z => z.Phone1);
var listOfPhone2 = (from x in table select x.Select(z => z.Phone2);
var listOfResults = (listOfPhone1.AddRange(listOfPhone2)).Distinct();
```

Comment: Hello Michel, i was hoping i could select data from both "Phone1" and "Phone2" in each row  in the same statement. is it possible ?

Comment: I don't know that ... hopefully someone else can shed a light on this... normally when using a from statement, you get one result back per 'iteration'; maybe by returning some kind of tuple and splitting it and distincting it might work, but doubt it will look better.

Comment: mmmkay..i see, i'll try your approach until i have a better solution. many thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
 var listOfResults = (from x in table
                       select new 
                            { 
                              Phone1 = x.Phone1, 
                              Phone2 = x.Phone2
                            }).Distinct();
```

or use groupby:

```
var listOfResults = (from x in table
                     group x by new { x.Phone1,x.Phone2 } into g
                           select new 
                                { 
                                  Phone1 = g.Key.Phone1, 
                                  Phone2 = g.Key.Phone2
                                });
```

### UPDATE:

```
var listOfResults = (from x in table
                                 select new[]
                                 {
                                     new { Phone = x.Phone1 },
                                     new { Phone = x.Phone2}
                                 }).SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library found here. They have a function called *DistinctBy* which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works with Linq-to-SQL, but with Linq-to-Object I would do it this way:

```
var unified = addresses.SelectMany(Row => new[] { new { Row, Phone = Row.Phone1 }, new { Row, Phone = Row.Phone2 } })
                        .Distinct(entry => entry.Phone)
                        .Select(entry => entry.Row);
```